# Doesn't analytically integrate sensibly let alone correctly

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

(This is induced x velocity on vortex sheet y=1+gtax/g+tx by strength 1+ac/X)

```
    Us[x_, g_, t_, c_] = a g^2 t*(g + t*x)* Integrate[
   (g +t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) {(g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + g^4 t^2 
                                                                
      a^2}),
      {X, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False, PrincipalValue -> 
      True]
```

a,g,t,c are all positive g=3/2 a= 1/6 t = 1.54419; c = .124775 so answer should be positive, At front of sheet x=0 evaluates indeterminate, for any positive x gives negative answer!  At x=0  hand simplifies to
a g^3 t *Integrate[(g + t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X) {(g + t X)^2
g^2
+ g^4 t^2 a^2}),
{X, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]/Pi

which does give positive value .308 that checks with a numerical integration

```
Please What's wrong with the general principal value integration back on the sheet?
```

Comment: I get a positive answer for $x=1$. I get the same negative answer for $x=10$ from both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`.  It makes me think the integrations are being done correctly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get negative value for $x=1$. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b91dH.png)  using the code below.

Comment: @Nasser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiaPx.png Similar result for `Integrate`, but it takes too long to evaluate to be worth my exploring.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am using exact numbers below. May be this is why there is a difference.

Comment: See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Comment: @Nasser Maybe. As I said, I think I got the same result plugging the numbers into the exact result of `a g^2 t*(g + t*x)*
 Integrate[(g + 
      t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) {(g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + 
        g^4 t^2 a^2}) /. x -> 1, {X, 0, Infinity}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False, PrincipalValue -> True, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, g > 0, t > 0, c > 0, x > 0}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, you did it different, that is why. You replace `x->1` in the integrand. I replaced `x->1` in the result. This is why. I will note this in my answer. It should not have made difference really.

Comment: I think I first did it without `x->1` inside, but I did have `Assumptions`. I'd bet the assumptions on `x` are important for `PrincipalValue` to work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, you are right, adding assumptions `x>0` and not replacing the integrand by `x->1` also produces positive value.  So now there are more than one way to get positive values. Negative values only show up when not using assumptions on `x` or when not replacing it by value before integrating. I have feeling this could be a bug, but I am no expert in this area. the integral is very tricky here.

Comment: Yes when I added the assumptions, I got the value I was after of +.308 at x=0.  Thanks everybody so much.

Comment: Sorry about  my wrong intuition that positive for all x which you have disproved and which created a diversion. Also when look at the ouput now for the symbolic integration (just symbols a,t,g,c) all the old imaginary stuff has vanished which also had me worried as How could thisI real integration produce imaginary numbers.

Comment: I did have {X, x, y, Y, n, c, t, f, a, L, VS, WS, q, g} \[Element] PositiveReals; which does not seem sufficient to tell it to get real

Comment: I tried to numerically verify these interesting results   `int[x_?NumericQ] := 
 a g^2 t*(g + 
    t*x) NIntegrate[(g + 
      t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) ((g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + 
        g^4 t^2 a^2)), {X, 0, Infinity} , Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
   Exclusions -> {x} ]` but  `NIntegrate` gives different results for `x=0: 0.969729 ` and `x=1: 0.00924032`. No idea why!

Answer (score 4):

> x=0 evaluates indeterminate, for any positive x gives negative answer!

Lets fix the code first. You had `{}` inside the integrand and better use exact numbers. And use `Limit` instead of replacing `x` to avoid `indeterminate`

```
g = 3/2;
a = 1/6 ;
t = Rationalize@1.54419
c = Rationalize@.124775
anti0 = Integrate[(g + 
     t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) ((g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + 
       g^4 t^2 a^2)), {X, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False, 
  PrincipalValue -> True];
anti1 = a g^2 t*(g + t*x)*anti0;

Limit[anti1, x -> 0] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You say the answer should be positive for any positive $x$, but why? This is not what the answer says

```
 Plot[(anti1 /. x -> 1), {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we step back and look at the integrand itself, you see it is negative from 0 to 1, then it becomes all positive after `x=1`

```
g = 3/2;
 a = 1/6 ;
t = Rationalize@1.54419
c = Rationalize@.124775
integrand = (g + t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) ((g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + g^4 t^2 a^2))
Plot[integrand /. x -> 1, {X, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
Plot[integrand /. x -> 1, {X, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I think this explains why you get negative value.

This is really a tricky one, because of the singularity at $X=1$, see

```
antiFirst = 
  Integrate[integrand, {X, 0, 1}, GenerateConditions -> False, 
   PrincipalValue -> True];
antiSecond = 
  Integrate[integrand, {X, 1, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False, 
   PrincipalValue -> True];
```

And now

```
Limit[antiFirst, x -> 1] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[antiSecond, x -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

There seem to be a problem, but from comment above thanks to  Michael, if you replace `x` in the integrand *before* doing the integration, then you get positive antiderivative. If you do it afterwords, you get negative result as shown above.  In theory it should not make difference, but replacing `x` in the integrand could greatly simplify the integrand and make it easier to do.

Compare

```
g = 3/2;
 a = 1/6 ;
t = Rationalize@1.54419
c = Rationalize@.124775
integrand = 
  a g^2 t*(g + 
     t*x) * (g + 
      t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) ((g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + 
        g^4 t^2 a^2));
anti0 = Integrate[(integrand /. x -> 1), {X, 0, Infinity}, 
   GenerateConditions -> False, PrincipalValue -> True];
anti0 // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With

```
g = 3/2;
 a = 1/6 ;
t = Rationalize@1.54419
c = Rationalize@.124775
integrand = 
  a g^2 t*(g + 
     t*x) * (g + 
      t X)/((1 + (a c)/X) (X - x) ((g + t X)^2 (g + t x)^2 + 
        g^4 t^2 a^2));
anti0 = Integrate[integrand, {X, 0, Infinity}, 
   GenerateConditions -> False, PrincipalValue -> True];
Limit[anti0, x -> 1] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So bottom line, replace `x` into the integrand before integrating to make life little easier for `Integrate`

Comment: Thanks for all the work everyone has done so quickly. I am still trying to digest it all. Physically I expect the induced velocity to be positive at all x and certainly at very small x where all the vorticity is at bigger x.

Answer (score 0):

So to try to summarise everyone else's super problem solving and remove a distraction my erroneous intuition caused, the simple answer to my question is just that a real integration, at least a Principal value one should include in the conditions list
Assumptions -> {a > 0, g > 0, t > 0, c > 0, x > 0}
where this list is declaring all parameters to be positive and definitely real. This suppresses strange  imaginary symbolic output, and corrected  wildly erroneous evaluations.